# Autoloading code duplicated between files generated via webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, laravel-mix

My app has a significant `app.js` (6k lines, 9MB) that needs to be split up for efficiency and loaded in smaller chunks, when and where needed.  What I'm attempting to do is load a second .js file only on some pages that uses components set in the first.  For example:

```html
<script src="/js/app.js?id=0ee4f7c5f4eaacfc778c"></script>
<script src="/js/sponsor.js?id=0ee4f7c5f4eaacfc778c"></script>
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .js('resources/assets/js/sponsor.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .version()
   .sourceMaps();
```

Using this approach `sponsor.js` is about 600 lines long (even though my component is only ~100) and it looks like 500 of those lines are a bunch of webpack autoloading code.  Technically this code already exists in the initial `app.js`.  **How can I create a separate bundle of vue components for a different section of my app without duplicating the webpack autoloading?**

Comment: Most of that code contains dependencies of `sponsor.js`, there may be 100 lines of `webpack` code whose effects are marginal considering run-time performance. If you have dependencies common to both files, see [extract](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/4.0/extract).